# Redmine CKEditor Removes Canned Response

Tags: ckeditor, redmine

Redmine CKeditor Plugin
When using Textile - The CannedResponse Button (from RedmineUP's Helpdesk plugin) shows fine.

When we switch to CKEditor it is no longer there.

How can i add the button that shows the canned resposnes from the helpdesk plugin?

I have no clue where to start and would really appreciate some insight